# Working with Box2D/Cocos2D in an external iOS project

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have followed the instructions as per [this article](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/) and have been working with Cocos2D without much issues. Recently, I tried including the Box2D headers to try some physics like so:

```
#import "Box2D.h"
```

This resulted in a lot of errors where the Box2D.h file could not include the rest of the header files:

```
../cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5/external/Box2d/Box2D/Box2D.h:34:0 ../cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5/external/Box2d/Box2D/Box2D.h:34:37: error: Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h: No such file or directory
```

That's the first error and the rest of the 23 are like that, but for the different headers in Box2D.h.

I have already added the projects/targets to the current project as per the instructions in the article, so my project currently looks like this:

[image]

Also, I have attempted to remedy this by selecting all .m files in my project and setting the file type to sourcecode.cpp.objcpp but do not think that this is the issue. I am certain that under the **User Header Search Paths** build setting, the folders where these headers are stored are added. If it weren't, Cocos2D wouldn't be able to compile either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is immediately obvious to other programmers, but I fixed this by checking the **Always Search User Paths** setting in the target settings. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Another solition for me is removing blank characters from directory names. Forexample if your project folder such as

```
"user/prj 01"
```

change it to

```
 "user/prj01".
```